# What method should I use to find the sum of the following serie?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to understand this:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-8n}$ using the geometric test

Comment: I am guessing because your series does not format properly-have you looked?  It looks like you are summing $e^{-8n}$, which is a geometric series.

Comment: Recall $e^{-8n} = \left(e^{-8}\right)^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the computation is rhe following:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-8n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (e^{-8})^{n},
\end{equation}
but, as $|e^{-8}|<1$ you can use the formula $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$ to obtain:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-8n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (e^{-8})^{n}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-8}}
\end{equation}